# Why Cocoapods command gives this error?

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, cocoapods

Why Cocoapods command gives this error in terminal? Either it is the problem with my settings or I am using VMware? Awaiting for your ideas & tricks.

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'pod' (>= 0) in any repository
>   ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'install' (>= 0) in any repository
>   ERROR:  Possible alternatives: installr, instant, instana, instacli, instapi

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`pod install` is `cocoapods` command, not part of `ruby` or `gem`. The error means there is no `pod` or `install` package in `ruby` package repository. After writing a proper `Podfile` in your Xcode project dir, just run `pod install`.

Comment: how to include ruby package repository? my pod file is absolutely correct I get review my pod file from my senior. but the problem is that pod install sometimes stops at 50% or 60% of downloading or sometimes gives this error.

Comment: @JackDowson What do you mean by `include ruby package`? Is there any ruby dependency you need? There is no `pod` in gem source. It has nothing to do with podfile.  You just can't run `gem install pod`.

Comment: what should I do? How can I solve my issue? is there any suggestions or ideas?